# Paypal Adaptive Payments Receiver Limit 1-5

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to switch over from Amazon FPS Marketplace to Paypal after numerous issues (won't go into them, not relevant).

I read that Paypal Adaptive Payments limits the amount of receivers from 1-5 in a chained payment, and between 2-6 in Parallel Payments. I don't quite understand this, how does that work in a marketplace environment? Customers could easily put 10 products from different sellers into their cart and check out. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 4):

Its a limitation you have to work around sadly. You'd need to validate customer baskets so they couldn't add more than 5 sellers products in one go. It depends on the kind of product, but to be honest this is relatively rare where you would have one customer checkout from 6+ seperate sellers. Don't get me wrong through... its annoying. Paypal should increase this to at least 10.

Answer (score 0):

As far as we know -- is there still no way to raise the limit on the number of receivers for Adaptive Payments?

Im looking to integrate this into our webstore, however, on more than a few occasions of past orders this limit would have failed the system, in that there would have been more than the 1 primary and 5 receivers.

I've emailed Paypal support, but I haven't received an answer -- If there is a Paypal developer monitoring this thread please chime in.

This thread was last updated in Aug of 2012, I would think after this period of time the request would have been made a number of times already.